# Shell script for remote login with password

Tags: shell, remote-access

I'm trying to write a shell script for remote login that doesn't ask for a password. Here's what I've tried and when I execute it, it still does ask for a password. Here's the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh ronnie-pc
expect "Password:"
send "password\r"
interact
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it and it takes a lot of time to login.

Comment: A better way to login via ssh is to use public-key authentication. More information on how to setup, you can find here: [Set up SSH public-key authentication to connect to a remote system](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews).

Comment: what Utlox said. If you really can't do that for whatever reason, you could also have a look at the [sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) program. But really, use public keys.

Answer (score 0):

why use shell? use pythons pexpect which works everywhere and easy to use.